# How can i check jsp form request submit in same jsp page? (enctype="multipart/form-data")

Tags: java, jsp, post, file-upload, request

```
<%
..... code to check request is submitted or not ...
%>
<form method="post" action="" name="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table >  
    <tr>    
      <td>Select up to 3 files to upload</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>    
      <td>   
        <input type="hidden" name="newFileName" value="newUploadedFileName1">
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile" >
        </td>    
    </tr>    
    <tr>    
     <td align="center">   
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload">
      <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Cancel">
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The jsp post request code to upload files will be in same page above in <% .. %> tag.

How can i add a check with if statement to check whether the Submit button is clicked or not , in other words whether a post request is sent or not.

I followed this , http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/SubmittingCheckBoxes.htm  but it did not help and that is to call a different jsp file ("formAction.jsp") not in same page .

```
if(request.getParameter("newFileName") != null) {
```

This statement always gives null value. I don't know why.

Note: it's a form with this attribute => enctype="multipart/form-data"

If i don't add any if statement then the files are uploaded for the first time , but next time if i click the reload button or refresh the page , the browser prompts me to resend the data or to reupload the previous files . I hope you have understood the problem. If there is any confusion to understand the problem please comment .

Can anyone give some hint/solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `multipart/form-data`, the request is been sent in a different encoding than the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding which the `getParameter()` and consorts is relying on. That's why they all return `null`. You need to parse the `multipart/form-data` request into sensible objects before being able to determine the submitted values. For that normally Apache Commons FileUpload or `request.getParts()` is been used. For further detail, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824).

Alternatively, you can also just check the request method. A normal request (link, bookmark, etc) is always GET. A form submit to upload the file is always POST.

```
if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
    // Form was submitted.
} else {
    // It was likely a GET request.
}
```

But this makes no utter sense inside a JSP. Writing raw Java code down in a JSP file is recipe for maintenance trouble. Rather submit the form to a fullworthy [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and just implement the `doPost()` method. In a servlet you've all the freedom to write Java code without taking all that HTML into account.